# Webpack & Angular: "Couldn't resolve resource ./foo.css relative to /project/src/foo.component.ts"

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to use Webpack instead of Gulp, the Angular component looks like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'application-databasebrowser',
    templateUrl: './core/applications/databasebrowser/databasebrowser.html',
    styleUrls: ["./core/applications/databasebrowser/databasebrowser.css"],
})
```

While I build with Webpack I get the following error:

> ERROR in : Couldn't resolve resource ./core/applications/databasebrowser/databasebrowser.css relative to /wrsoftware/cOS/Juno/src/client/core/applications/databasebrowser/databasebrowser.component.ts

The Project uses scss files in the source but even if I rename "databasebrowser.scss" in the src folder to "databasebrowser.css" the error stays the same.

Webpack config:

```
// const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ScriptExtPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');
const { AngularCompilerPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');


module.exports = function () {
    return {
        mode: 'development',
        entry: './src/client/core/cos.entry.ts',
        // watch: true,
        output: {
            path: __dirname + '/dist/client',
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.scss']
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['@ngtools/webpack'] },
                { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
                { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
                {
                    test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
                    use: [
                        { loader: 'style-loader' },
                        { loader: 'css-loader' },
                        { loader: 'sass-loader' }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                // { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets'}
            ]),
            new ScriptExtPlugin({
                defaultAttribute: 'defer'
            }),
            new AngularCompilerPlugin({
               tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
               entryModule: './src/client/core/cos.module.ts',
               sourceMap: true
            })

        ]
    };
}
```

Comment: Wow. Most people put their component's html/css right next to the template file. Is yours really that many child folders away?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I understand what you mean, but the typescript, html and css files are in the same directory :) The path "./core..." is seen from the root directory of the web server. If I change templateUrl to './databasebrowser.html' and styleUrls to ["./databasebrowser.css"], I get: ERROR in : Couldn't resolve resource ./databasebrowser.css relative to /wrsoftware/cOS/Juno/src/client/core/applications/databasebrowser/databasebrowser.component.ts
Project works fine with gulp^^

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got the solution.

While gulp wants the absolute path, webpack wants the relative path AND wants the scss file - not the css file like gulp does.

So the solution is to change the component to:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'application-databasebrowser',
    templateUrl: './databasebrowser.html',
    styleUrls: ["./databasebrowser.scss"],
})
```